# Marketing Software Online

Tags: ads, shareware, google-ads-api

What are some resources in use for marketing downloadable desktop software online? AdWords, certainly, and "organic" search engine results but is anyone having any luck making sales through sites like Tucows and/or Download.com anymorE?

Comment: Why is this a programming question, again?

Comment: Because some programmers here may be running small ISVs, and they need to figure out how to sell their software.

Comment: Yeah, without the salesmen, programmers don't get paid.

Answer (score 1):

[Joel on Software forums](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to market your software online.  Some cost money, many do not.  Consider the following:

- Start a blog and update it regularly with items of interest to your potential customers
- Create forums where users can report bugs, ask for help, and suggest features.  Build a community around your product that potential customers can find.  Many will judge you by what those in your community say about your products.
- Submit press releases when you have announcements.  There are many free, and some paid, sites that accept press releases.  Don't forget announcements forums, newsgroups, and [mailing lists](http://aspadvice.com/lists/SignUp/list.aspx?l=7&c=16).
- Create screencasts and post them to your site, as well as to community video sites like YouTube.
- Purchase advertising targeted as narrowly as possible to your prospective customers.  If your target is Microsoft developers, for instance, consider [Lake Quincy Media](http://lakequincy.com/) and [CodeProject](http://codeproject.com/) as good places to start.